# How to do Inner class object instantiaton with `new` Coffescript?

Tags: java, javascript, syntax, coffeescript

In Java, you could do something like this:

```
public class World{
  String name;
  World(String name){this.name = name;}

  public class WorldObject{
    String type;
    WorldObject(String type){this.type = type;}

  String display(){ return type + " on " + name;}
  }
//…
  public static void main(String[] args){
    World w1 = new World("Jo"),
          w2 = new World("Kallisto");

    WorldObject sand = w1.new WorldObject("sand"),
                rock = w2.new WorldObject("rock");

    System.out.println(sand.display());
    System.out.println(rock.display());
  }
}
```

I wanted to emulate the same, or a similar, invocation syntax in coffeescript and ran into some anaesthetic formulations and am asking for some simpler solutions.

First of, I'm pretty sure Javascript doesn't allow for the nice inference of `name` as Java does in this case, but **please correct me if I'm wrong**. Thus I figured I'd have to go with something like `outer.name`, but that's only of little concern. Note that this program prints

```
sand on Jo
rock on Kallisto
```

as should the resulting coffee scripts.

The simplest solution would be to go with a factory method.But I don't like factory methods, because the `new` keyword is always a very strong indicator that you create a new object. You could do that, but if you do, the instantiation of a WorldObject does look different.

```
class World
  constructor: (@name) ->

  worldObjectFactory: (bar) -> new @WorldObject(bar,@)

  WorldObject: class @WorldObject
    constructor: (@bar, @outer) ->
    display:    ()-> "#{@bar} in #{@outer.name}"


w1 = new World "Jo"
w2 = new World "Kallisto"
sand = w1.worldObjectFactory "sand"
rock = w2.worldObjectFactory "rock"

console.log obj.display() for obj in [sand, rock]
```

Another variation would be, to "sneak in" the outer object via `defineProperty`, but it looks ugly and messes with the things an user might expect. Furthermore, the syntax still isn't what I want (but the closest):

```
class World
  constructor: (@name) ->

  WorldObjectFactory = (outer) -> class @WorldObject
    constructor: (@bar) -> @outer = outer
    display:    ()-> "#{@bar} in #{@outer.name}"

  Object.defineProperty World.prototype,
    "WorldObject",
    {get: ()-> WorldObjectFactory @}


w1 = new World "Jo"
w2 = new World "Kallisto"
sand = new w1.WorldObject "sand"
rock = new w2.WorldObject "rock"

console.log obj.display() for obj in [sand, rock]
```

**Is there a way to get Java's syntax (`w1.new WorldObject("sand")`)?** I know how to get to 
`w1.new WorldObject, "sand"`, but this exposes the factory method outside the World class.

And, **if not, is there a way to write the second solution in a more coffe-script ideomatic way**? I just recently got more interested in coffeescript, so it might be that there are nicer way to write this that I haven't come upon. (I haven't found a coffeescript translation for javascript's `World.propotype = {…, get WorldObject(){…},…}`, for example).

Comment: would you consider dependency injection a valid option?

Comment: if the syntax is roughly the same, and the declaration isn't to cluttered, I'll go with it. currently I'm experimenting with ` w1.new WorldObject: "sand"`, looks pretty good, imo